# How to hide elements in a Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, stackview

I have 4 separate views and I want to hide the other 3 of them when one of the buttons is pressed.

I have them in a UIStackView but `.isHidden = true` does not hide the views for some reason.

It works fine when they're not in a stack view.

```
@IBAction func qbpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    QBContainer.isHidden = false
    WRContainer.isHidden = true
    RBContainer.isHidden = true
    QBIndicator.isHidden = false
    WRIndicator.isHidden = true
    RBIndicator.isHidden = true
    TEIndicator.isHidden = true
    QBButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.5008062124, blue: 1, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    WRButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    RBButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    TEButton.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1), for: .normal)

    if intersitial.isReady{
        intersitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } 
}
```

[image: stack view]

Comment: isHidden should work. You may need show post your code

Comment: just posted, isHidden works when the views are not in a stack view, but does not work when I put them in a stack view

Comment: Either the properties (`QBContainer`, `WRContainer`, etc.) are not connected to those views, or something is setting the `isHidden` properties back to `true`. Use the debugger to figure out which.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

isHidden property doesn't work, but you can use alpha and achieve the same result,

`QBIndicator.alpha = 1.0` will work for `QBIndicator.isHidden = false` and
`QBIndicator.alpha = 0.0` will work for `QBIndicator.isHidden = true`

Comment: every API apple writes you find a bug making a nest and raising a family, because that crap will never be solved. StackViews have a decade.

Answer (score 13):

setting a view to hidden should make it no longer visible, regardless of whether or not it inside a `UIStackView`.

The benefit of `UIStackView` is that it provides free animation through the isHidden property, like so:

```
// Assuming stackViewSubView.isHidden == false here
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    self.stackViewSubView.isHidden = true
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```